# Pandas merge in same table with multiple columns producing unexpected output

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, inner-join

I have a dataframe `df` with columns: [`value`, `arg1`, `arg2`, `diff_value`]. I want to find all rows where (diff_value, arg1, arg2) is in `df` (as the first 3 columns). My code to do this is:

```
contains_df = df.merge(df, 
                left_on=['value', 'arg1', 'arg2'], 
                right_on=['diff_value', 'arg1', 'arg2'])\
                .drop(columns=['value_y', 'diff_value_y'])\
                .rename(columns={'value_x':'value', 'diff_value_x':'diff_value'})
```

I would then assume that `df[df.value == 'a']` where `'a'` is the value of `diff_value` in row 1 of `contains_df` would produce at least one row. However, I get no rows, implying that my merge did not do what I expected it to. How do I fix this?

For example, with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'arg1': [1, 1, 0, 0],
                   'arg2':[0, 0, 1, 1], 'diff_value':['z', 'a', 'b', 'y']})
```

I would expect the result to be row 2: `[value:'b', arg1:1, arg2:1, diff_value:'a']` as (`'a'`, 1, 0) is in row 1 as (value, arg1, arg2). However, instead the output is row 1.

Comment: Can we see some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first values in the `left_on` and `right_on` merge need to be swapped.

```
contains_df = df.merge(df, 
            left_on=['diff_valuevalue', 'arg1', 'arg2'], 
            right_on=['value', 'arg1', 'arg2'])\
            .drop(columns=['value_y', 'diff_value_y'])\
            .rename(columns={'value_x':'value', 'diff_value_x':'diff_value'})
```

This produces the desired result.